# How to test ANTLR translation without adding EOF to every rule

Tags: unit-testing, antlr

I am in the middle of re-writing my translator and I am being much more disciplined about tests this time, since this version is likely to live for more than a few weeks.

Because you can run a visitor starting at any node, you can *almost* write beautiful small tests like this ...

```
expect(parse("some test code", "startGrammarRule")).toEqual(new ASTForGrammarRule())
```

and then write one ( or a few of these ) for each visitor function

EXCEPT that the rule you are invoking is a sub rule, and so does not have "EOF" in it, so if my grammar has somewhere in it

```
numberList: NUMBER ( ',' NUMBER )* ;
```

... then `parse("1,2,3", "numberList")` only parses "1" (because it is only an "EOF" which would make the parser hungry enough to consume all the string).

Editing the rule to add EOF is a non starter. I could, for every rule I write a test for, add a test version of the rule ...

```
numberList: NUMBER ( ',' NUMBER )* ;
numberList_TEST: numberList EOF ;
```

... but that is going to make the grammar cluttered and introduce worry that the `_TEST` rules have to always be maintained scrupulously ...

I want a flag when I create a parser which constructs that faux TEST rule dynamically and then parses from there, or something like that ...

Is there a better way to write tests for my parser that I haven't figured out yet?

Comment: Maybe you could import the grammar into a test grammar that has a rule `test : ( nonterm1 | nonterm2 | ... ) EOF;` for each nonterminal in the imported grammar.

Comment: Possible that language would not parse because phrases which are never alternatives in the full language are now in play. Interesting idea though, I like it.

Comment: maybe something like:  `test: ( 'numberlist' numberlist ) | ( 'otherrule' otherRule) EOF`

Comment: Of course it'll parse more than what you want. But you then check the first child of root so that the type conforms to what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Java project, I'm using a custom matcher to check if the parsed tokens are 100% of the tokenstream, and if not, will fail.

You seem to use the TypeScript target, so in TypeScript that could look like this:

### T.g4

```
grammar T;

parse      : numberList EOF;
numberList : NUMBER ( ',' NUMBER )*;

NUMBER : [0-9]+;
ID     : [a-zA-Z]+;
WS     : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

### parserMatchers.ts

```js
import { TLexer } from '../src/parser/TLexer';
import { BailErrorStrategy, CharStreams, CommonTokenStream } from 'antlr4ts';
import { TParser } from '../src/parser/TParser';
import { Lexer } from 'antlr4ts/Lexer';

expect.extend({
  toBeCompletelyParsedBy: (source: string, ruleName: string) => {
    const lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    lexer.removeErrorListeners();
    const tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    const parser = new TParser(tokenStream);
    parser.removeErrorListeners();
    parser.errorHandler = new BailErrorStrategy();
    const context = parser[ruleName]();

    // Collect the real tokens: non-HIDDEN and non-EOF tokens
    const realTokens = tokenStream.getTokens().filter((t) =>
      t.channel === Lexer.DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL && t.type !== Lexer.EOF);

    let indexOfStop = realTokens.indexOf(context.stop);
    let pass = realTokens.length === (indexOfStop + 1);

    let message = () => {

      if (pass) {
        return `Expected '${source}' not to be completely parsed by rule '${ruleName}', but it did.`;
      }

      let offending = realTokens[indexOfStop + 1];

      return `Expected '${source}' to be completely parsed by rule '${ruleName}', but '${offending.text}' ` +
        `(${offending.line}:${offending.charPositionInLine}) was not included!`;
    };

    return { pass, message };
  }
});

declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
      toBeCompletelyParsedBy(ruleName: string): R
    }
  }
}

export {};
```

And in you unit tests, you can now do this:

```js
import './parserMatchers';

test('the numberList parser rule', () => {
  expect('3, 4, 5').toBeCompletelyParsedBy('numberList');
  expect('3, 4, 5 FOO').not.toBeCompletelyParsedBy('numberList');
});
```

Comment: Had to make a couple of changes to get my typescript environment to consume the code, but it basically worked like a charm. Thanks!