# Which rule does the string match?

Tags: antlr

I'm using the Java syntax defined at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java

My users are free to input any thing, for example

```java
assert image != null;
```

,

```java
public Color[][] smooth(Color[][] image, int neighberhoodSize)
{   
    ...
}
```

,

```java
package myapplication.mylibrary;
```

, and

```java
import static java.lang.System.out; //'out' is a static field in java.lang.System
import static screen.ColorName.*;
```

My program should tell which syntax the input matches.

What I have up to now is

```cs
var stream = CharStreams.fromString(input);
ITokenSource lexer = new JavaLexer(stream);

ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
Parser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);
parser.ErrorHandler = new BailErrorStrategy();

try
{
    var tree = parser.statement();
    Console.WriteLine("The input is a statement");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The input is not a statement");
}
```

Are there better way to check the input match any of the 100 rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no other way than trial-and-error. Note that your generated parser has the property:

```java
public static final String[] ruleNames
```

which you can use in combination with reflection to call all parser rules automatically instead of trying them manually.

Also, trying `parser.statement()` might not be enough: the input `String s = "mu"; FUBAR` could be properly parsed by `parser.statement()` and leave the trailing `Identifier` (`FUBAR`) in the token stream. After all, the `statement` rule probably does not end with an `EOF` token forcing the parser to consume all tokens. You'll probably have to manually check if all tokens are consumed before determining the input was successfully parsed by a certain parser rule. Also see this Q&A: [How to test ANTLR translation without adding EOF to every rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689300/how-to-test-antlr-translation-without-adding-eof-to-every-rule)

Comment: `parser.statement()` is merely one example. I would have to write 100 try-catch blocks, each detects a different rules. If I view your answer correctly, the keyword is reflection, you are asking me to use reflection to call these rule methods, instead of manully writing it 100 times.

Comment: That is correct. Also make note of my remark about EOF

Answer (score 0):

Unless you *really* mean that your users can enter *anything* (and I would suspect that, with some thought, that’s not really the case)

You could add a parser rule that includes alternatives for each construct your users could enter.  You might have to take a little care on the order.

Since parser rules are evaluated recursive descent, if your new rule isn’t referenced by any other rules, it would have no impact on the rest of the grammar.

Could be worth a shot.